# Cannot Update UI elements in Blazor

Tags: user-interface, blazor

My Main issue is that after updating the variables and calling the StateHasChanged(), UI just does not update. Now I have even made a simple counter code and still UI will not change. I have tried Several things i'm reading online Including Changing where i am implementing the code including the onInilizedAync(). So im hoping someone can look at the basic counter code and point out what could be causing this. And what im missing here. The reason i want things async is in the main Project i grab data from a 3rd party server to update the variable, lol i just can't use the data on the UI.

```
@iii

@code{

int iii = 0;
System.Threading.Timer timer;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async \_ =\>  // async void
{
await InvokeAsync(() =\> iii++);

        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }, null, 0, 1000);

}
}
```

Comment: Are you in .Net8 ? What is you render mode ?

Comment: Thanks for having a look, Im using .Net 8. As for the render mode the blazor app is in default configuration when starting a new Blazor server app. Looking at the Program.cs it has `builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();` and i have not added any Directives to the Component .razer page. Otherwise im not sure on the render mode, Sorry for being naïve i appreciate the help.

Comment: Im Back again you solved my issue thanks T.Trassoudaine. After you asked about render modes i added `@rendermode InteractiveServer` directive to the component and now it works. I appreciate the kick in the butt. I'll keep an eye out for this for now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was the render mode `builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();` Was already in Program.cs, But didn't have the directive `@rendermode InteractiveServer` on the .razer page. Once that was added everything worked.